# Need to retrieve specific column from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a code that will pull any text options from column B without any of the blank cells. I want to be able to add additional text items to the spreadsheet and have them appear in the dropdown without having to change the code. I also do not want any blank options when there the selection I have made in the code includes blank cells.

[image: Link to Spreadsheet]

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
  var list = ws.getRange(1,2,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  Logger.log(list);
```

Comment: Look into the duplicate questions linked above your post

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var list = ws.getRange('B1:B6').getValues().flat()
// pop off the empty ones at the end
while(list[list.length - 1] === '') list.pop()
// add more to list
list = [...list, 'more', 'stuff', 'added']
// save them in B
ws.getRange(`B1:B${list.length}`).setValues(list.map(v => [v]))
```

Comment: I'm sorry I miss-typed my original question. 

I am trying to build a code that will pull any text options from column B without any of the blank cells. I want to be able to add additional text items to the spreadsheet and have them appear in the dropdown without having to change the code. I also do not want any blank options when there the selection I have made in the code includes blank cells.

Comment: Use B:B for the full column, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...

Comment: If I use B:B, I get everything in column B including all the empty cells in column B and if I do B:B6 then I am restricted to only 6 cells even if only one of them is empty and have to change the code if I remove 1 option from the spreadsheet. 

So how can I grab everything in B1 to the last row in B that has text?

Comment: I showed you how to pop off the trailing empties.

Answer (score 0):

To "grab anything in column B up to B6 " is the same as `B1:B6`, so, instead of

```
ws.getRange(1,2,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1)
```

use

```
ws.getRange('B1:B6')
```

Comment: I'm sorry I miss-typed my original question. I want it to be able to pull whatever is in column B.

Comment: @AaronDolgin Please edit the question to clarify what are you looking for.